# where is debug options in instruments?

Tags: ios, instruments

[Instruments CoreAnimation's Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQtNB.png)

Why can't I find "debug options" in Xcode 9.3's instruments?
Can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: Update your question with what you mean by "debug options" and where you found them in previous versions of Instruments. If you do not provide this additional information, no one will be able to solve your problem.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk I could find it next to the "input filter"，but I can't find it  now

Answer (score 21):

"The Core Animation instrument and template have been deprecated in Instruments. The functionality previously under "Debug Options" has moved to Xcode, under "Debug > View Debugging."

Source: [Xcode Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html)

Comment: For iOS simulators the Xcode option is  disabled. The option is available from the simulator debug menu.